# How to change default message validation on bootstrap

Tags: html

how to change message default upload file on bootstrap from "please a select file" to "please upload document" ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label for="file" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Unggah Dokumen</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It is working for me.

```
<input type="text" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter Shop Name')">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<input name="myfile" class="form-control" type="file"  required=""  
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please upload document')"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

more information about other options
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: for the first validation was successful, but after I uploaded the document, and I click the button, did not proceed to the next process, but still run the validation, even though I have uploaded the document,
check this link - > https://imgur.com/a/TuVoc

Comment: can you post your whole code? for me this worked. Also I forgot to add the name attribute to  the input element, fixed that in an edit.